# Java Not found when using JBOSS, although it exists

Tags: java, ubuntu, jboss

What am I missing to get JBOSS to add user for Management console and also start jboss server?[image]

Comment: might be sudo issue. can you run ls -la in /usr/bin/java and see what access it shows?

Comment: it shows -  /etc/alternatives/java

Comment: I get this response when searching for java  - amitpandey@ubuntu:~$ whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/bin/X11/java /usr/local/java /usr/share/java

Comment: can you try cd /usr/local/java and then ls -la

Comment: I dunno.  What ARE you missing?  Have you looked through anything about JBoss to see what it requires?  Do you have JAVA_HOME and any other environment variables mentioned for JBoss set up?  If you enter "java -version" from a command line, does it execute properly?  How are you attempting to run JBoss?  Do you get an error message?  What IS it?  I suppose it's a bit much to suggest that SO outlaw one-line questions, but it isn't the worst idea I've thought of...

Comment: from the update -alternatives statement we can see that java is installed and the JAVA_HOME path is available. the path is also available...yet jboss add-user.sh says java is not available. Does an sh files have problem with an *? I would try it out and update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That script is quoting the java command so it attempts to use `"/usr/local/java/jdk*/bin/java"` which is invalid. If you unset your `JAVA_HOME` or give it a proper directory it will work.